# How should a Minimum Equipment List (MEL) be used?

Tags: faa-regulations, regulations, student-pilot, mel

I want to make sure that I understand how an MEL is used.

Does this list have instruments that are needed or not needed to conduct safe operations?

For example, if I have an altimeter that’s inoperative, but it is a part of the MEL, does that mean I cannot operate that aircraft?

Answer (score 3):

**Question: Does this list have instruments that are needed or not needed to conduct safe operations?**

The short answer is "**not needed**."

Generally, all equipment/components/instruments installed on/in an aircraft are required to be operational for flight unless properly deferred in accordance with the aircraft's Minimum Equipment List (MEL). The aircraft's MEL lists the items that may be inoperative, the deferral of which is conditioned upon satisfying specifically stated provisos. If the piece of equipment that is inoperative is listed in the MEL and the provisos (if any) are complied with, the aircraft can be safely operated.

**Question: For example, if I have an altimeter that’s inoperative, but it is a part of the MEL, does that mean I cannot operate that aircraft?**

No, it's essentially the opposite of that. If the inoperative item is listed in the MEL, and the provisos can be satisfied, the aircraft can be operated.

Using a B737 as an example, the image below shows what the requirements are to operate the aircraft with an inoperative Standby Attitude Indicator. As shown below, if the Standby Attitude Indicator is inoperative the aircraft may be flown if the provisos listed in column 4 are complied with.
([Source - Draft Boeing-B737 Master Minimum Equipment List](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/draft_docs/media/afx/MMEL_B-737_Rev_62_Draft.pdf)) (**DRAFT ONLY, for example only - not to be used**)

[image]

As a note, columns 1, 2, 3, and 4 of the MEL are defined in the "Table Key" on the top part of the page (image above).  These columns are self-explanatory, except for column 1 (Repair Category).  The repair categories identify when the inoperative component must be repaired. (see the Repair Categories list below):

> Category A. This category item must be repaired within the time interval specified in the remarks column of the certificate holder’s approved MEL.
>
> Category B. This category item must be repaired within 3 consecutive calendar-days (72 hours), excluding the day the malfunction was recorded in the aircraft maintenance record/logbook.
> For example, if it were recorded at 10 a.m. on January 26, the 3-day interval would begin at midnight on January 26 and end at midnight on January 29.
>
> Category C. This category item must be repaired within 10 consecutive calendar-days (240 hours), excluding the day the malfunction was recorded in the aircraft maintenance record/logbook. For example, if it were recorded at 10 a.m. on January 26, the 10-day interval would begin at midnight on January 26 and end at midnight on February 5.
>
> Category D. This category item must be repaired within 120 consecutive calendar-days (2880 hours), excluding the day the malfunction was recorded in the aircraft maintenance log and/or record. ([Source, page 4](https://www.nata.aero/assets/Site_18/files/committee_mtgmemos/bestpracticemineqlistbp.pdf))

Comment: The size and scope of the MEL has a massive impact on dispatch reliability and schedule completion rate. You can get a lemon design with a DR of 96% at entry into service several points higher just by getting enough items added over time. The OEM will spend years working on getting components and subsystems added and the MEL grows and grows, each item adding another fraction of a percent to the DR, without even fixing the unreliable components themselves.

Answer (score 3):

For an airplane to be airworthy, it must comply with its type certificate.

For smaller airplanes, there is something called an equipment list and is typically found in the POH.  This equipment list (not the MEL) will show all equipment that was installed on the aircraft when it was certificated.  All the -R (required) equipment must be installed while -A (additional) or -O (optional) equipment does not have to be installed.

If any of the required equipment is not working or broken, the aircraft is no longer airworthy.  It would not be ideal to ground an airplane due to a burned-out light bulb, so the concept of the MEL (minimum equipment list) was created.

The MEL will list all items that can be **inoperative** for flight.  As @757toga mentioned in his answer, you must comply with any conditions on the MEL for the inoperative equipment to be airworthy for flight.

I personally think the name `minimum equipment list` adds to the confusion of what the documents' purpose is.  It is the maximum equipment that can be inoperative for flight and still be airworthy provided the conditions are met.

---

- Equipment List: Will list all equipment on the airplane and mark as either required, additional or optional.
- Minimum Equipment List:  Will list all equipment that can be inoperative for  flight provided the conditions are met.
- Kind of Operation Equipment List:  Equipment required for certain operations (i.e. day or night, VFR or IFR, etc.)